# How to stop increment of Numeric stepper in Flex

Tags: flex4, numericstepper

In single click the value of numeric stepper increments continuously till we release the mouse.I need one value increment in each click.How to achieve this in Flex 4 Numeric stepper?

Comment: That's not the normal behavior of a `NumericStepper` Have you any code? Specifically, show us how to reproduce your problem, otherwise I don't think your question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Override the click handler , handle the event manually 
Just in case if you want to override the whole click behaviour ..
use event.preventDefault();